# Creating a link tag with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a link tag that i am creating from javascript. now i want to append a parameters to that link just like below example.so that when the user clicks that button it should go to that url along with the paramenters

```
var id="123456789";
var data = '<a href="/order/product/ + id"> click</a>' ;
```

this data tag i am appending to some other element.
now i can able to call /order/product. but when i give id also it is giving error "missing arguments"!!
 can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to unquote the string where the variable goes

```
var id   = "123456789";
var data = '<a href="/order/product/' + id + '"> click</a>' ;
```

Or on really up-to-date JavaScript engines that support ES2015+ template literals:

```
var id   = "123456789";
var data = `<a href="/order/product/${id}"> click</a>`;
```

But that won't work on any version of IE (does on Edge).

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier both to write and read (and debug too), I'd recommend the following variant of how to organize the code:

```
var id = "1234566",
    // It is more understandable now that hrefLink contains id concatenated with some other string
    hrefLink = "/order/product/" + id,
    link = document.createElemen('a');
link.href = hrefLink;
```

In this way you

1. See what variable means what
2. Control what your `hrefLink` consists of
3. Follow best practises when instead of multiple lines with `var` statement you explicitly "show" where the declaration section is:

   ```
   var a = smth1,
       b = smth2;
   ```

So just by looking at this code you easier understand that that is a code chunk of variables declaration

Answer (score 1):

For easy create link you can use method `link(str)` of `String`:

```js
var id="123456789";
var linkText = " click";
var href = "/order/product/" + id;
var data = linkText.link(href);
alert(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **remove the quotes from id**

just like below

```
var id="123456789";
var data = '<a href="/order/product/' + id  +'"> click</a>' ;
```

If You have id within quotes means it will take as string not a variable name and so just remove the quotes. It will work

Comment: Wrong quotes on `id` and we got string `<a href="/order/product/" + id  +"> click</a>` instead of `<a href="/order/product/123456789> click</a>`